# Ubuntu 18.10: No Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.10

I installed the OS on my 2nd computer.
I plugged in my USB Wi-Fi adapter, Ubuntu recognized it, but when I tried to connect to my home network - this error message popped up:
[image]

Thanks for helping!

Comment: We need more information. For example, what is the relevant output of `dmesg` and `lsusb`?

Answer (score 0):

By the time of posting the main post, the USB was plugged to one of the front USB ports.
I plugged the adapter to one of the USB ports in the back (if it matters - to a USB 3 port) - and I could successfully connect to my home network!
And the best part - switching back to the front USB port still worked!